# Toolbar.js by Paul Kinzett Event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, toolbarjs

I'm wanting to use toolbar.js from http://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar but even though I have the tool bar working the the handling of the events as documented I don't seem to be able to get identify which toolbar button/icon I clicked.

Below is the code snippit, which it pretty much lifted from the example site.

I'm no expert in JS, so if someone could enlighten me as to how to handle the toolbarItemClick event so that I can preform the correct action, that would be awesome.

Thanks
Lionel

```
<div id="user-options" class="toolbar-icons" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="tooltip-container normal">';
    <section class="left">';
        <div id="normal-button" class="settings-button"><img src="/3rdparty/paulkinzett-toolbar/documentation/img/icon-cog-small.png" /></div>';
    </section>';
</div>


$('#normal-button').toolbar({content: '#user-options', position: 'top'});

$('#normal-button').on('toolbarItemClick',
            function(event) {
                console.log(event);
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure out the same thing, eventually i deciphered the mechanism. A bit late to help you but maybe it will save someone else some time.

Firstly, I gave the button anchor tags IDs, though one could use data- attributes etc (note i am using img tags instead of the default glyph support)

```
<div id="user-toolbar-options">
    <a id="menu-insert" href="#"><img src="add.png" width="18px" height="18px" /></a>
    <a id="menu-remove"  href="#"><img src="remove.png" width="18px" height="18px" /></a>
</div>
```

The key is to use a different function signature which isn't publicized in the documentation (`function (event, buttonClicked){}`, the 2nd parameter (buttonClicked) is the a element that was clicked on.

in the code below i also set targetBlock to the div that the button was in (as i have potentially dozens of articles and the button thats hows the toolbar appears on each) so i need to get the article in question to act on it.

```
$('#normal-button').on('toolbarItemClick',
                function (event, buttonClicked) {
                    var targetBlock = $(event.target).parents('.article') // get article
                    var buttonClickedID = buttonClicked.id // get the id of the button click

                    switch (buttonClickedID) {
                        case 'menu-insert':
                            insertNewArticleBelow(targetBlock)
                            break;
                        case 'menu-remove':
                            removeArticle(targetBlock)
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#button').toolbar({
 content: '#toolbar-options',
 position: 'top',
 style: 'primary',
 event: 'click',
 hideOnClick: true
});

$('#button').on('toolbarItemClick',
   function( event,buttonClicked ) {
      alert(buttonClicked.id);
   }
);
```

```html
<link href="https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/css/documentation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/css/jquery.toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/js/jquery.toolbar.min.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar-options" class="hidden">
   <a href="#" id="plane"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
   <a href="#" id="car"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
   <a href="#" id="bycicle"><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a>
</div>

<div data-toolbar="toolbar-options" data-toolbar-animation="flip" class="btn-toolbar feature-toolbar btn-toolbar-primary text-center" data-toolbar-style="primary" id="button"><i class="fa fa-cog" style="position: relative"></i></div>
```