# How to apply toolbar.js in a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use toolbar.js but in a loop. Here is an example from [stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256891/toolbar-js-by-paul-kinzett-event-handling)

Here is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/hemantr/757L1m6L/7/) which I am trying to apply, in this code I have a main container, in which I am creating many div dynamically and in those div I trying to put tooblar. please let me know how to make it work or what I am doing wrong.P

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<link href="https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/css/documentation.css" rel="stylesheet"/> <link href="https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/css/jquery.toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/js/jquery.toolbar.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <h1 id=aa>

  </h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
for (var id = 0; id <= 10; id++) {

  var divTool = $('<div id=toolbar-options' + id + ' class="hidden"><a href="#" id=plane' + id + '><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a><a href="#" id=car' + id + '><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a><a href="#" id=bycicle' + id + '><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a></div><div data-toolbar="toolbar-options" data-toolbar-animation="flip" class="btn-toolbar feature-toolbar btn-toolbar-primary text-center" data-toolbar-style="primary" id=button' + id + '><i class="fa fa-cog" style="position: relative"></i></div>');

  var div = document.createElement('div'),
        h = document.createElement('h3')
    divId = "id" + id,
    hId = "idh" + id,
    container = document.getElementById("container");
  div.setAttribute("id", divId);
  h.setAttribute("id", hId);
  container.appendChild(div);
  h.innerHTML = id;
  $(div).append(h);
  $(div).append(divTool);

}

$('#' + 'button' + id).toolbar({
  content: '#toolbar-options',
  position: 'top',
  style: 'primary',
  event: 'click',
  hideOnClick: true
})

$('#' + 'button' + id).on('toolbarItemClick',
  function(event, buttonClicked) {
    alert(buttonClicked.id);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that is what you looking for.

JS:

```
for (var id = 0; id <= 10; id++) {
    var div=$('<div class="btn-toolbar" style="margin:5px;"></div>');
    $('#container').append(div);
  $(div).toolbar({
    content: '#toolbar-options',
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 550px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<div id="toolbar-options" class="hidden">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a>
  </div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stiwari/757L1m6L/9)